# HTML encode on a XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to convert some value from a XML attribute into valid HTML with entities. So that for example the string `"olá"` from the XML would be transformed from the XSLT into `"ol&#225;"`

I can't find any xsl function to do this.
Any ideas ?

Comment: As long as your HTML document uses the correct encoding you won't need to escape characters like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify `us-ascii` encoding in `xsl:stylesheet` element. The following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html" encoding="us-ascii"/>

    <xsl:variable name="data" select="'olá'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>olá - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$data" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives:

```
ol&#225; - ol&#225;
```

The `xml` method in `xsl:stylesheet` gives the same result with the standard XML heading.

Comment: The problem is that xsl:text only works with literal values. I would like to encode a value coming from the input XML and xsl:value-of doesn't seem to care about the output encoding.

Comment: I used `xsl:text` for simplicity only. It works with `xsl:value-of` as well, I have checked it. I will add an example to my initial answer.

Comment: @Hugo: Either way, `xsl:text` and `xsl:value-of` should both work. `<xsl:variable name="foo" select="'olá'"/><xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>` produces `ol&#225;`.

Answer (score 0):

I´m pretty sure you´ll find this template useful:
Download this xslt and check the one called "url-encode-num"
http://advanced-internal-onebox.googlecode.com/files/obox_stylesheet.xslt

It transforms any special character... Well, any of  the ones listed here with their numeric encodings:

```
<xsl:variable name="latbis">¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ"&lt;&gt;=</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="digit1">111111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222220000</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="digit2">666666666777777777788888888889999999999000000000011111111112222222222333333333344444444445555552777</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="digit3">123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123452465</xsl:variable>
```

But is easy to update.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Pablo

Comment: the provided link is currently broken